# Model multiple field-lookup in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, url, slug, permalinks

I have a model

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('type', 'slug'),)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('model_detail', (), {'type': self.type.slug, 'slug': self.slug})
```

and urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<type>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', ModelDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
)
```

and a DetailView

```
class ModelDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'detail.html'
```

but I get the exception MultipleObjectsReturned because the slug isn't unique. I want the urls to be `/type/slug/`, so the model can contain two records with same slug, but different types, so urls could be `/1/slug/` and `/2/slug/` with different results. How can I tell the model to use both type and slug as lookup instead of just the slug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to 'tell the model' to use the type and string fields -- it's the class based view you have to override.

I suggest you override the `get_queryset` method, to restrict the queryset to objects of the correct type. An alternative would be to override the `get_object` method.

```
class ModelDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Restrict queryset to objects of the correct type
        """
        return MyModel.objects.filter(type_id=self.kwargs['type'])
```

See the Django docs on [dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) for more details.